# Prop always null in react

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a component which has to display the object details. This is instantiated from a TableComponent on click of a row.
The object id is passed:

```
<ObjectDetails objectID = {id}/>
```

This is my ObjectDetails component:

```
class ObjectDetails extends Component {

componentWillMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(loadObjectDetails(this.props.objectID));
}

render() {
    console.log("props------" + JSON.stringify(this.props));
    ....
}

let select = (state) => ({objectDetails: state.objectDetails});

export default connect(select)(ObjectDetails);

}
```

`loadObjectDetails` populates the store with objectDetails. I can see that the store does have the details. 
But in `render()`, props always has objectDetails as null.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, any help please?

Edit:
Adding few more details

```
export function loadObjectDetails(objectID) {
return function (dispatch) {
Rest.get('/rest/objects/' + objectID).end(
  (err, res) => {
    if(err) {
      dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_OBJECT_DETAILS_FAILURE', error: res.body})
    } else {
      dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_OBJECT_DETAILS_SUCCESS', objectDetails: res.body})
          }
     }
   )
  }
}

export default function objectDetailsReducer(state={
  objectDetails: null,
  error: null,
}, action) {

switch (action.type) {
case "FETCH_OBJECT_DETAILS_SUCCESS": {
  return {...state, objectDetails: action.objectDetails, error: null}
}
case "FETCH_OBJECT_DETAILS_FAILURE": {
  return {...state, error: action.error }
}
}
return state
}

const middleware = applyMiddleware(promise(), thunk, logger())

export default compose(middleware)(createStore)(combineReducers({ reducer1, reducer2, objectDetailsReducer}))
```

Comment: The `export default` statement is inside the class definition. Mistake?

Answer (score 3):

The object inside your mapStateToProps function is what gets passed as props:

```
 {objectDetails: state.objectDetails}
```

So in your component, you can access: `this.props.objectDetails`. And whatever properties are on that. If you just wish to pass the objectID, update your mapStateToProps function to change that.

Comment: I'm able to access objectID. This is what my log inside render is showing:
`{"objectID":"1234","objectDetails":null}`

Comment: Ah sorry, missed your first line. Can you post the code for your reducers, and how you're creating your store?

Comment: Added details in the question

Comment: Cheers. Sorry for late reply. Try changing the map function to: `let select = (state) => ({objectDetails: state.objectDetailsReducer.objectDetails});`. The state coming through connect is an object containing the reducers themselves. If that doesnt work, try debugging the function and see what's coming through.

Answer (score 1):

if you want component get new props when store mutates, you have to use `mapStateToProps` can see many samples in docs: http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html

In your sample code you have extra spaces around `=` sign:

`<ObjectDetails objectID = {id}/>`.

`componentWillMount` function is fired once when component will mount and that's it, so you dispatch this action, it updates the store, but you don't have `mapStateToProps` so this component has no reaction to store updates.

Component can react to store by `mapStateToProps` or you can leave this component presentational but then upper component has to have `mapStateToProps`.

You can read about presentational component on same page: http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html

Component will try to re-render only when props or state is changed. If props/state is not changed - no re-render happens. Your props don't change. You don't use state on this component at all, so nothing changes too.

Answer (score -1):

The `render()` method was throwing an error on the first render which is why it was not rendering on `props` change.
It is re-rendering after I fixed that error.

Sorry for wasting your time!